# Stripe Subscription Disable Auto-Renewal in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, subscriptions

I have a rails app where users buy a subscription through Stripe for varying lengths of time.  When the subscription period expires, the subscription is auto-renewed through basic Stripe subscription functionality (aka, that's how Stripe works).

I would like to do two things.

1. Show a subscriber when the subscription is going to expire and
2. Provide an on/off switch for auto-renewal.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Stripe subscription docs](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/cancelling-pausing), you can cancel the subscription to avoid auto-renewal:

```
subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve("sub_3R3PlB2YlJe84a")
subscription.delete(:at_period_end => true)
```

Remember to pass `:at_period_end => true`, else subscription will cancel immediately.

If customer wants auto-renewal, you can [reactivate cancelled subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/cancelling-pausing#reactivating-canceled-subscriptions), by setting the plan to the same ID as the current plan.

```
subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve("sub_3R3PlB2YlJe84a")
subscription.plan = {PLAN_ID}
subscription.save
```

Comment: Thanks @Utsav-Kesharwani  I'll try this in my next update.